# React Native Text Overflows the Screen Width with FlexWrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I am trying to implement a component in react native where i have a row of  and  components but i can't achieve the result i want.

the current code:

```
      <View style={{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexWrap: 'wrap'
      }}>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', borderRadius: 100, paddingHorizontal: 10 }}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, lineHeight: 18 }}>test</Text>
        </View>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, lineHeight: 18 }}>
          afnsdas idaspidn apdnasdk asdnkasdn sdknsdk sdknd sdasdas
        </Text>
      </View>
```

The bubble "test" is shown on one line and then random text inside  goes overflow and jumps on a new line. If i make it shorter and create a separate  component, it works fine.

How to to achieve the result of showing long string on the same line with bubble "test" and make text break line only when it reaches the end of view?

[image]

wanted result:
[image]

Comment: also, if i remove `paddingHorizontal` for some reason the view with bubble becomes flex view and the text does not go below the bubble

Answer (score 1):

To achiеvе thе dеsirеd layout in Rеact Nativе,  whеrе you havе a row with a bubblе "tеst" and tеxt that brеaks to a nеw linе only whеn it rеachеs thе еnd of thе viеw,  you can makе usе of a combination of flеx and flеxWrap propеrtiеs along with somе additional styling.  Hеrе's how you can modify your codе:

```
<View style={{
  flexDirection: 'row',
  alignItems: 'center',
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
  maxWidth: '100%', // Ensure the view doesn't exceed its parent width
}}>
  <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', borderRadius: 100, paddingHorizontal: 10 }}>
    <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, lineHeight: 18 }}>test</Text>
  </View>
  <Text style={{
    fontSize: 12,
    lineHeight: 18,
    flex: 1, // Allow the text to take up remaining space
    marginLeft: 10, // Add some spacing between the bubble and text
  }}>
    afnsdas idaspidn apdnasdk asdnkasdn sdknsdk sdknd sdasdas
  </Text>
</View>
```

If you add maxWidth: '100%' to the parent view and set the text margin flex: 1 and marginLeft: 10, you will ensure that the text is divided into new lines only when it reaches the end of the view, and you have a gap between the bubble and the text that will be there.

These rules should help you find the settings you want.

Comment: it still shows as two columns. The text has two lines now but its cut off on the left side

Answer (score 0):

The second `Text` goes overflow and jumps on a new line because you have `flexWrap: 'wrap'` in the parent `View`.

The solution is very simple: Just remove this `flexWrap: 'wrap'` style.

By the ways, you should set `flex: 1` to secound `Text` to make it break line when it reaches the end of view correctly:

```
    <View style={{
      flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems: 'center',
      // flexWrap: 'wrap',
    }}>
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', borderRadius: 100, paddingHorizontal: 10 }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, lineHeight: 18 }}>test</Text>
      </View>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, lineHeight: 18, flex: 1 }}>
        afnsdas idaspidn apdnasdk asdnkasdn sdknsdk sdknd sdasdas
      </Text>
    </View>
```

Comment: this makes bubble appear vertically on the middle of the parent view and the second text cuts off before the bubble.

Comment: it should go all in one line

Comment: Can you add 1 image of result you looking for?

Comment: added the image